# How to optimize this SQL query summing amounts across related tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, relational-database

I have an Access project that implements SQL, and I have been working on optimizing a reconciliation process. This process uses a voucher system which links all tables together.
Each record in each table has a specific voucher ID in which an amount is associated with.
The vouchers themselves are unique and can contain multiple voucher numbers, which can be seen below.

```
Table: Rec_Vouchers
v_id       v_num      voucher
1          12341234   12341234
2          10101010   10101010;22222222
2          22222222   10101010;22222222
...
```

I have 8 other tables that are linked by these voucher ID's. I'm trying to join all of the tables together to show the distict voucher ID and voucher and all corresponding sums of amounts for each table with that specific voucher ID. Below is the query and a sample of the results. I've worked on this for a while now, and it's starting to give me a headache. This query works, but takes way to long to execute.

Also, at some point, I need to match all of these values together to determine if a voucher is "Matching", "Not matching", or "Matching with a difference". So far I've only tried creating a function within the below code that would return a string value of "M", "NM", or "MwD" to display in the column for each voucher. Again, this works, but takes an extremely long time. I've also tried letting VBA do the dirty work with the query's returned recordset, and this takes a good amount of time too, but not as long as creating the function within my sql query. This is the next step, so if you could help with all of this that would be great, but I really just need to optimize the query I have given.

I know this is a lot to wrap your head around, so let me know if you need any more information. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
select a.v_id, a.voucher,
(Select sum(b.amount) from rec_month_4349_test b where b.voucher = a.v_id) as GL, 
(Select sum(c.payments) from rec_daily_balancing_test c where c.voucher = a.v_id) as DB,
(Select count(x.v_num) from rec_vouchers x where a.v_id = x.v_id and x.v_num not like 'ONL%') as GLcount,
(select count(c.batch_num) from rec_daily_balancing_test c where a.v_id = c.voucher) as DBcount,
(select sum(d.amount) from rec_ed_test d where a.v_id = d.voucher) as ED, 
(select sum(e.batchtotal) from rec_eft_batches_new_test e where a.v_id = e.voucher) as EFT, 
(select sum(f.batchtotal) from rec_check_batch_test f where a.v_id = f.voucher) as CHK, 
(select sum(g.idxtotal) from rec_lockbox_test g where a.v_id = g.voucher) as LBX, 
(select sum(h.amount) from rec_lcdl_test h where a.v_id = h.voucher) as LCDL, 
((select sum(i.payment_amount) from rec_electronic_files_test i where a.v_id = i.voucher) + (select sum(j.amount) from rec_electronic_edits_test j where a.v_id = j.voucher)) as Elec
from rec_vouchers a
group by a.v_id, a.voucher
```

---

```
Sample Results:
v_id     GL         DB         GLcount   DBcount     ED     EFT     CHK     LBX     LCDL     Elec
6131     19204.00   19204.00   1         1           NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
6132     125330.00  14932.00   6         6           NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     14932.00
6133     18245.00   NULL       2         0           NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
6175     98.93      98.93      1         1           NULL   98.93   NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
```

Comment: Why is this labelled sql-server if everything is in MS Access?

Comment: you asking optimization for access or SQL Server ?

Comment: Everything is not in Access. All of the rec_* tables are SQL tables in a database. All Access will do is call the view that I have created above to export the results to an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: OK that means the view is basically joining these tables and giving the final result set and Access is calling that view to get the result set. so the view is running in SQL DB engine and you can definitely take advantage of having Clustered and NonClustred Index on same table. please see the answer i posted.

Answer (score 0):

It is tempting to say that the "traditional" way to write this query is by moving the tables to the `from` clause using `join` predicates.  However, that would probably introduce unnecessary cartesian products.  Your method is actually ok; the alternative would be doing `left join`s to aggregated subqueries.

The killer on performance is probably due to cycling through the tables to find the matches.  You can significantly improve performance by having an index on the fields used in the `where` clause for each query.  For the first two tables, for instance, you should have an index on `rec_month_4349_test(voucher)` and `rec_daily_balancing_test(voucher)`.

In SQL Server, you can further optimize this query by including the variable used for summation in the index as well.  The following indexes would be better:  `rec_month_4349_test(voucher, amount)` and `rec_daily_balancing_test(voucher, payments)` (or you can include them in the index without being searchable, which is a bit more advanced).

This optimization works in most databases (an index-scan rather than an index-lookup).  I don't know if it works in MS Access (a software product that I try to avoid when possible).

Remember, you would need to do this for all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I created separate views for each table to select the voucher and the sum of the amounts for each specific voucher. Each view looked similair to the following:

**rec_sum4349**

```
SELECT voucher, sum(amount) AS GL
FROM rec_month_4349_test
GROUP BY voucher
```

I then have one view that combines all of the separate view together using full joins like the following:

**rec_vouch_test**

```
SELECT a.voucher, a.GL, b.DB
FROM rec_sum4349 a
FULL JOIN rec_sumDB b
ON a.voucher = b.voucher
WHERE a.voucher IS NOT NULL AND a.voucher <> ''
ORDER BY a.voucher
```

After I saw that this worked really well, I created the views for the rest of the tables that I needed summed amounts for and added them to the above view. The results are exactly what I was looking for and the run-time was cut down from almost 2 minutes to the matter of a couple seconds! Thanks for all the help. Now on to matching everything up!

Answer (score 0):

correlated sub queries is the last choice i would prefer.

i would suggest to write sub-query and join each table so that each table can utilize the indexes on them.

Create the following indexes on each table and see the below query.

**rec_vouchers**

Clustered Index (v_id , voucher)

Filtered Non Clustered Index(v_num) WHERE v_num NOT LIKE 'ONL%'

**rec_month_4349_test**

Non Clustered Index(voucher) Include (amount)

**rec_daily_balancing_test**

Non Clustered Index(voucher) Include (payments)

**rec_ed_test**

Non Clustered Index(voucher) Include (amount)

**rec_eft_batches_new_test**

Non Clustered Index(voucher) Include (batchtotal)

**rec_check_batch_test**

Non Clustered Index(voucher) Include (batchtotal)

**rec_lockbox_test**

Non Clustered Index(voucher) Include (idxtotal)

**rec_lcdl_test**

Non Clustered Index(voucher) Include (amount)

**rec_electronic_files_test**

Non Clustered Index(voucher) Include (payment_amount)

**rec_electronic_edits_test**

Non Clustered Index(voucher) Include (amount)

```
    SELECT a.v_id,a.voucher
            ,t1.GL ,t2.DB ,t3.GLcount
            ,t4.DBcount ,t5.ED ,t6.EFT
            ,t7.CHK ,t8.LBX ,t9.LCDL
            ,(t10.Elec1+t11.Elec2) AS Elec
    FROM
    ( SELECT  t0.v_id ,t0.voucher
        FROM rec_vouchers t0
        GROUP BY t0.v_id ,t0.voucher
    )a
    JOIN
    ( SELECT SUM(b.amount) AS GL,b.voucher
      FROM rec_month_4349_test b
      Group By b.voucher
    ) t1
        ON a.v_id=t1.voucher
    JOIN
    ( SELECT SUM(c.payments) AS DB,c.voucher
      FROM rec_daily_balancing_test c
      Group By c.voucher
    ) t2 
        ON a.v_id=t2.voucher
    JOIN
    ( SELECT COUNT(x.v_num) AS GLcount,x.v_id
      FROM rec_vouchers x
      WHERE x.v_num NOT LIKE 'ONL%'
      Group BY x.v_id
    ) t3 
        ON a.v_id=t3.v_id
    JOIN
    ( SELECT COUNT(c.batch_num) AS DBcount,c.voucher
      FROM rec_daily_balancing_test c
      Group By c.voucher
    ) t4 
        ON a.v_id=t4.voucher
    JOIN
    ( SELECT SUM(d.amount) AS ED,d.voucher
      FROM rec_ed_test d
      Group By d.voucher
    ) t5 
        ON a.v_id=t5.voucher
    JOIN
    ( SELECT SUM(e.batchtotal) AS EFT,e.voucher
      FROM rec_eft_batches_new_test e
      Group By e.voucher
    ) t6 
        ON a.v_id=t6.voucher
    JOIN
    ( SELECT SUM(f.batchtotal) AS CHK,f.voucher
      FROM rec_check_batch_test f
      Group By f.voucher
    ) t7 
        ON a.v_id=t7.voucher
    JOIN
    ( SELECT SUM(g.idxtotal) AS LBX,g.voucher
      FROM rec_lockbox_test g
      Group By g.voucher
    ) t8 
        ON a.v_id=t8.voucher
    JOIN
    ( SELECT SUM(h.amount) AS LCDL,h.voucher
      FROM rec_lcdl_test h
      Group By h.voucher
    ) t9 
        ON a.v_id=t9.voucher
    JOIN
    ( SELECT SUM(i.payment_amount) AS Elec1,i.voucher
        FROM rec_electronic_files_test i
        GROUP BY i.voucher
    ) t10 
        ON a.v_id=t10.voucher
    JOIN
    ( SELECT SUM(j.amount) AS Elec2,j.voucher
        FROM rec_electronic_edits_test j
        GROUP BY j.voucher
    ) t11
        ON a.v_id=t11.voucher
```